# RollupError: Could not resolve entry module

Tags: vite

[image: file structure]

I got below error for this vite.config.js

Could not resolve entry module "src/service-worker.js".
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "src/service-worker.js".
at error (file:///C:/Users/liang/OneDrive/Desktop/learn/Sanbox_2023/my-vite-app-test/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2124:30)
at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///C:/Users/liang/OneDrive/Desktop/learn/Sanbox_2023/my-vite-app-test/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24011:20)
at async Promise.all (index 0)

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      outDir:"./wwwroot/",
      input: {
        sw: resolve(__dirname, './src/service-worker.js'),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames(chunk) {
          return chunk.name === 'sw' ? 'service-worker.js' : 'assets/[name]-[hash].js';
        },
      }
    }
  },
})
```